# Unable to assign POST data from multiple check boxes

Tags: php, mysql

I am a newbie to PHP and MySQL, so please ignore my bad practice of coding :)

Ok, here's the scenario:

I have a page, checkin.php which has two forms;
Form 1: Takes some input and displays data from database along with multiple checkboxes.
Form 2: It is dynamically generated if any data is found above.

Here's the code:

```
//Echoing out the query results
              echo "<form method='POST' action='checkin.php'>";
              echo "<tbody>";


              foreach ($checkin_status as $row) {
                echo "$rowStart";
                  echo "$row[book_id]";
                echo "$insertColumn";
                  echo "$row[branch_id]";
                echo "$insertColumn";
                  echo "$row[card_no]";
                echo "$insertColumn";
                  echo "$row[fname]" . " " . "$row[lname]";
                echo "$insertColumn";
                  echo "$row[date_out]";
                echo "$insertColumn";
                  echo "$row[due_date]"; 
                echo "$insertColumn";
                  //Checkbox creation
                  $checkin_recall_value = "$row[book_id]" . " " . "$row[branch_id]" . " " . "$row[card_no]";
                  echo "<div style='text-align: center;'><input type='checkbox' name='checkin' value='$checkin_recall_value'></div>";
                echo "$rowEnd";
              }

              echo "</tbody>";

              //Checkin button in foot
              echo "<tfoot>"; 
              echo "<td colspan='7' style='text-align: center; padding-right: 20px;'><input id='checkin_button' type='submit' value='Check In' title='Click to check in!'></td>";
              echo "</tfoot>";

              echo "</form>";
```

The form is generated with checkboxes along side the returned tuples.

Now when I am selecting some checkboxes and trying to display, it WONT...

Here is the code:

```
if(!empty($_POST['checkin'])) {

      //Retrieving the recall variables as an array from POST and assigning to $main_array
      $main_array = array();
      //echo "I am here";

        if(is_array($_POST['checkin'])) {
          foreach($_POST['checkin'] as $value)
          {
            $sub_array = explode(" ", $value);
            array_push($main_array, $sub_array);
          }
        }

        print_r($main_array);
}
```

Its returning an empty array...
Please help me fix this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IF you want to have multiple html elements with the same name, you must define it as an array, adding `[]`:

```
<input type='checkbox' name='checkin[]' value='$checkin_recall_value'>
```

Comment: I had initially used 'checkin[]' but had some issues with undefined 'checkin' name, so had removed it to check for other fixes..

I fixed the error but forgot to replace [] , my bad, my bad...

thanks a ton!